# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have continuous cdfs, then $X-Y$ has a continuous cdf.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

My question is this:

> Prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with continuous cdfs, then $X-Y$ also has a continuous cdf.

I can prove this in many ways if I am allowed to use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ have densities. Then I can say that $X$ and $-Y$ are independent and I can use convolution to arrive at a density of $X-Y$. Or I can use the Jacobian formula and arrive at a density .

But I am to use the fact that a random variable is continuous if it's cdf is continuous and that's it. If it has density then it is absolutely continuous. So I am not allowed to use the density argument.

So if I am to show that $X-Y$ is continuous then I am to basically prove that $F_{X-Y}(a)-F_{X-Y}(a^{-})=0\,\,\,\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$

This is what I have tried.
Let $h>0$ be an arbitrary positive real number .

$$F_{X-Y}(a^{-})=\lim_{h\to 0}F_{X-Y}(a-h)=\lim_{h\to 0}P(X-Y\leq a-h)$$

How do I proceed?. Any help is appreciated. I am unfamiliar most of measure theoretic approach to probability, so please try and explain in basic analysis terms.

Comment: Usually, the phrase "$X$ is a continuous r.v." means that "$X$ has a density". This is *not* equivalent to saying that "The cdf of $X$ is continuous". For example, if $X$ has the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution), then $X$ has a continuous cdf, but does not have a density. Instead, we can say "$X$ has a density if and only if the cdf of $X$ is *absolutley* continuous." So, my question is; are you supposed to prove $X$ and $Y$ have continuous cdfs implies $X+Y$ has continuous cdf, or are you supposed ot prove $X,Y$ have density implies $X+Y$ has density?

Comment: The former. X and Y have continuous cdf then X-Y has a continuous cdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X-Y$ does not have a continuous c.d.f. Then for some value $c$ in the support of $X-Y,$ we have $\Pr(X-Y=c)>0.$ Then from the law of total probability we get
$$
0<\Pr(X-Y=c) = \operatorname E(\Pr(X-Y=c\mid Y)) = \operatorname E(\Pr(X= c+Y\mid Y))
$$
The conditional probability $\Pr(X=c+Y\mid Y)$ is a random variable that is completely determined by $Y.$ Since its expected value is positive, then there is some value $y$ of $Y$ for which it is positive. So $\Pr(X=c+y)>0.$ Thus the c.d.f. of $X$ has a discontinuity at $c+y.$

Comment: +1 nice proof. The formal definition and existence proof of $Pr(X \in A \: | \: Y)$ does still require some measure theory though.

Comment: It's a great proof. But is there a way to do it without expectation?. Maybe by using sequences or maybe continuity of the marginal cdf s?

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen I agree. I think measure theory is unavoidable, since general cdfs correspond to general measures.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen : True. But I suspect measure theory is not the final word.

Comment: @Michael Hardy Why such an excellent answerer as you are can have reputation score 1 ? What has happened ?

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to assume that the cdf of $X$, $F_X$ is continuous. Take a sequence $\{a_n\}$ converging to $a$ from the left. Then,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}(X-Y\le a_n)&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathsf{E}[\mathsf{P}(X\le a_n+Y\mid Y)] \\
&= \mathsf{E}\!\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}(X\le a_n+Y\mid Y)\right]
\end{align}
by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Now,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X\le z+Y\mid Y)=F_X(z+Y) \quad\text{a.s.}
$$
Since $F_X$ is continuous,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}F_X(a_n+Y)=F_X(a+Y) \quad\text{a.s.},
$$
and thus,
$$
\mathsf{E}\!\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}(X\le a_n+Y\mid Y)\right]=\mathsf{P}(X-Y\le a).
$$